# Use GREP to replace a body of text

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

What is best way to use GREP to replace text from `in` through `</div>` with
`walked down the path`

```
The cat in the hat
jdlsknklnvlsdknld       ======>    The cat walked down the path
jkgsabkjkjksjakh
</div>
```

Comment: grep doesn't modify text.

Comment: You can use the command 'sed' for that.

Answer (score 3):

Matching multiple lines can be fairly easily done using Perl.

```
perl -p0e 's# in .*</div># walked down the path.#sm'
```

Briefly put,

- `-p0e` turn Perl into a `sed`-like streaming multi-line processor.
- The `s#...#...#` portion signifies that you want to replace all characters from `in` to `</div>` (the first clause) with `walked down the path` (the second clause).
- `sm` roughly means "treat newline symbols as all other characters.

This answer assumes that the input text has only one such pattern.

Relevant documentation pages can be found [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) and [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) on Perl's official website.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` to replace text? Good luck with that.

`sed` will do it for you:

```
sed 's/in the hat/walked down the path/;/The cat/,/<\/div>/ {/The cat/n;d}' file
```

#### Notes

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `;` separates commands
- `/begin/,/end/` operate within a range from the line with `/begin/` to the line with `/end/`
- `{}` grouping, for commands to use on the range
- `/The cat/n` exclude the line with `/The cat/` (do nothing and read the next line)
- `d` delete (the rest of the lines in the range)